# Can I use AR view if my phone doesn't have a gyroscope?

Tags: pokemon-go

My 'AR' view in Pokemon Go doesn't work. Every time I switch it to on it gives me an orientation error. I found out that it could be because my phone lacks a Gyroscope.

My question is, will I be able to play Pokemon Go in AR mode?

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't be able to play in AR mode without a gyroscope. It is absolutely required, as it's the only way to check your phone's orientation.